# Terraform: Add Access Policy to Cloudwatch Destination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

TLDR version: Is it possible to use an aws_cloudwatch_log_destination as a cross-account subscription filter for CW log ingestion?

I'm building a centralized logging solution in Terraform, basically a rehash of AWS's Central Logging solution seen here: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/centralized-logging/

In the AWS Cloudformation template, they build a Cloudwatch Destination as a custom resource which ingests a list of spoke accounts for use as principals which are allowed to send logs to the destination. The Helper Lambda functions process the custom resources and set them up for use.

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement something similar in Terraform. There is a resource for this, aws_cloudwatch_log_destination, but it does not seem to contain any access information regulating which log source accounts are allowed to use the CW destination as a subscription filter. Consequently, the subscription filter cannot be used on any log groups in external AWS accounts - as no external accounts are allowed to use the CW destination. Throws an error anytime I try to use it.

Comment: So you want to have the same architecture from the article?

Comment: Yes - and I was able to migrate all infrastructure into Terraform. But the only lingering problem is the Cloudwatch destination. I cannot see how to create those for cross-account log ingestion using Terraform - there are ways of doing that manually, but they do not translate into TF.

Comment: There might be a way using the awscc provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_stream